# Complex inverse hyperbolic cosine

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry, complex-numbers, inverse, hyperbolic-functions

It is well known that the hyperbolic cosine $\cosh$ induces a bijection from $[0,+\infty)$ to $[1,+\infty)$, with its inverse given by
$$
\forall t\in[1,+\infty),\quad\operatorname{arcosh}(t)=\ln(t+\sqrt{t^2-1}).
$$

I am interested in the extension in the complex plane of this. It would be natural to set
$$
\forall z\in\mathbb C,\quad\operatorname{arcosh}(z)=\ln(z+\sqrt{z^2-1}).
$$

Yet many authors (including [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_hyperbolic_functions#Principal_value_of_the_inverse_hyperbolic_cosine)) define it as
$$
\forall z\in\mathbb C,\quad\operatorname{arcosh}(z)=\ln(z+\sqrt{z+1}\sqrt{z-1}).
$$

Wikipedia mentions that the second definition allows us to speak of $\arccos(z)$ for imaginary $z$. I don't find it very convincing, because I consider the square root defined on $\mathbb R_-$ as well. So I was not able to understand what the first definition really fails to achieve, and what advantage the second one really brings. Any help or reference would be appreciated.

Comment: $\sqrt{z^2-1}=\sqrt{(z+1)(z-1)}=\sqrt{z+1}\sqrt{z-1}$.

Comment: I believe that is not true for the complex square root. In general $\sqrt{ab}\neq\sqrt a\sqrt b$. For instance $1=\sqrt1=\sqrt{(-1)\times(-1)}\neq\sqrt{-1}\sqrt{-1}=i^2=-1$.

Comment: Principal square root of a complex number is in the right half plane (branch cut on negative real axis), so multiplying two square roots can cover the whole plane.

Comment: I see your point. But then why does everyone agree to define $\operatorname{argsh}(z)=\ln(z+\sqrt{z^2+1})$? Something happens for cosine in particular, and I don't understand what exactly.